# Why doesn't my form within the ng-app directive submit (angularjs)?

Tags: angularjs

I'm just getting started with angularjs and noticed that forms within a `ng-app` directive won't submit. Any ideas of how I can make the form submit?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="foo" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form) :

> Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the `<form>` element has an `action` attribute specified.