# AngularJS blocks submit button in symfony2 form

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I have form created in symfony2, which at the end renders button to submit form. When I add `ng-app="myApp"` everything works fine, but I can't submit form which is on this page. Why is that and how to unblock this?

FORM:

```
->add('company','choice',array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr'=>array('ui-select2'=>'myArray', 'ng-model'=>'form.company','ng-options'=>'option.value as entity.name_company for entity in entities','ng-change' => 'changeItem()')
            ))

            ->add('project',null,array(
                'attr'=>array('ui-select2'=>'myArray2', 'ng-model'=>'form.task','ng-options'=>'option.value as entity.description_task for entity in tasks')
            ))
```

VIEW:

```
<html ng-app="flowApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('external-libs/select2/select2.css')}}">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('external-libs/select2/select2.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('external-libs/select2.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('external-libs/app.js') }}"></script>
        <style>
                .select2-choice { width: 220px; }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{ form(form) }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module('flowApp', ['ui.select2']).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    }
);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $element,$http) {


    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'companies.json'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

         $scope.entities = data.entities;
         $scope.form = {company: $scope.entities[0].value };
         console.debug(data.entities);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add some code please? Are you using angular for anything here?

Comment: yep, I'm using for the filling select with select2 script. I've added code.

Comment: Okay. First of all. $scope.forms is a variable, and you are invoking it as a function (why are you doing `{{ form(form) }}`?). Otherwise, are you seeing network traffic for your GET request?

Comment: {{ form(form) }} is symfony function to render form.....

Comment: isn't it `{[{ form(form) }]}` ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 2):

Well [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) says:

> For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission
>   to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute
>   specified

so you can add action attribute to your form. In my example i am using grenerateUrl function, but you should generate url of your current route(route of controller where the form is generated)

```
$data = array();
            $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data,
                array("action" => $this->generateUrl("route_to_curent_path"))))
                ->add('field', 'text')
                ->add('submitButton', 'submit')
                ->getForm();
```

**EDIT:**
just now found out that this is a  duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353796/form-will-not-submit-when-placed-inside-ng-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178686/why-doesnt-my-form-within-the-ng-app-directive-submit-angularjs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069810/empty-action-attribute-on-a-form-with-angularjs?lq=1)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945837/angular-js-submit-form-old-way?lq=1)(this link being the most upvoted answer)

Answer (score 0):

We need more informations, did you let browser validate form ? To remove :

```
{{ form(form, { 
    'attr': {
        novalidate,
    },
    }) 
}}
```

Maybe errors popup are hidden (happen with various complexe form fields)

When you said "i can't submit", is the submit button unable ? Errors happen after sumbission ?

Comment: nope, code is as simple as You see. When I remove "ng-app" than everything works just fine. submit button is enabled, just doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Had you try to remove auto-validation so ? It's the default behaviour on mostly recent browsers.