# symfony submit button does nothing

Tags: angularjs, symfony, doctrine, twig

What am I doing wrong here? When I press the submit button on this form (Symfony 2.8) nothing happens. Here is the controller:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/SetuporgController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Organisation;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SetuporgController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/organisation/setup", name="setuporg")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $organisation = new Organisation();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($organisation)
              ->add('name', TextType::class)
              ->add('email_reminders_on', CheckboxType::class)
              ->add('email_reminder_frequency', ChoiceType::class, array (
                  'choices' => array(
                      'fortnightly' => 'fortnightly',
                      'weekly' => 'weekly',
                      'daily' => 'daily',
                  ),
                  'choices_as_values' => true,
              ))
              ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save Changes'))
              ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($organisation);
            $em->flush();

            return new Response('Organisation created successfully');
        }

        return $this->render('default/testform.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

For the moment I am testing with just

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

in the template. Everything looks ok, but pressing the button does nothing. I am following the documentation, but it's not clear what I'm missing. I have tried explicitly adding the method as POST, but that didn't change anything. I have read through the other questions that resembled this one and they all had different problems to mine.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens" ? Your form is submitted, or when you click nothing happens ? If so, it's probably a client side problem, do you have some Javascript preventing the form to be submited, or some HTML5 validation (E.g. required fields) ?

Comment: +1 , open your console/network tabs and see, if the page is reloaded it's more than nothing and it's server side, if it doesn't the problem is surely coming from client side

Comment: Thank you both for responding. It has pointed me in the right direction. angular.js is somehow preventing submission. Does this mean I need to use angular to submit the form?

Comment: OK I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937286/angularjs-blocks-submit-button-in-symfony2-form

Thank you both again.